# Can you call a controller function from a view in CakePHP?

Tags: cakephp

I want to call a controller function from a view.
Is that possible in Cake PHP?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is possible via the [requestAction method](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#requesting-elements-from-a-plugin), but it is not recommended due to a slight performance hit. Use it wisely.

As [Xr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/109813/xr) noted in the comment, using requestAction often signifies design issues (MVC separation).

Comment: Not exactly massive (not anymore, at least): http://cakedc.com/developer/mark_story/2009/02/27/benchmarking-requestaction .

Still, if you want to call a controller function, you probably have problems with how you separated functionality between the parts of the MVC model.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I've completely missed that article.

Answer (score 2):

Yeap use requestMethod with Caching

```
$out = Cache::read('savedincache');
if(empty($out)){
   $out = $this->requestAction('/articles/myfunction');
   Cache::write('savedincache', $out);
}
```

in /app/controllers/articles_controller.php

```
function myfunction(){
   $out = $this->Article->find('all');
   return $out
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I have successfully done the following (CakePHP 2.3).

Say you have "MyController" with a public function named "functionToRun()".

From your View file:

```
$variable = new MyController();
$variable->functionToRun($parameter);
```

Note that the "$this->request" object will not be available, so if you need that data in the function, you'll have to pass it in as a parameter, and perhaps make changes to the function to allow for that.

I'm not going to argue about whether or not this is a good idea, although it should be noted that sometimes the Building is on fire, and you have to put it out yesterday. I will concede that probably the overall design should have been better, but we don't have time to rebuild Floors One through Three just because we discovered the issue when we got to Floor Five.

Given a choice of rule-breaking, I much prefer breaking this rule than the one about code duplication, which to my admittedly limited knowledge is the only remaining alternative. Code duplication leads to much worse maintenance nightmares.

Answer (score 0):

`requestAction` method is bad idea, if you need to set variable from controller i think it's better if you move your controller code to the model and then in app_controller.php, from `beforeFilter` function you can use your model and then call your function from your model